# Get UTI of NSPasteboardTypeFileURL

Tags: cocoa, uti, nspasteboard, nsworkspace

`NSFilenamesPboardType` got deprecated on 10.14 and the suggestion is to use `NSPasteboardTypeFileURL`. This gives me filename as

> file:///.file/id=6571367.12885025918

and `NSWorkspace` is unable to get UTI out of it.

How to get UTI from `NSPasteboardTypeFileURL`?

Old code:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
    NSDragOperation resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationNone;
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {
        NSArray <NSString *>*list = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        NSString *firstItem = [list objectAtIndexedSubscript:0];
        NSError *error;
        NSString *UTI = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] typeOfFile:firstItem error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[NSImage imageTypes] containsObject:UTI]) {
                resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationCopy;
            }
        }

    } else if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF]) {
        resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationCopy;
    }

    if (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationCopy && resultingDragMask & NSDragOperationCopy) {
        return NSDragOperationCopy;
    }
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

With `NSPasteboardTypeFileURL` I get error which states file doesn't exist. Dragged from pasteboard:

> Printing description of error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “id=6571367.12885025918” couldn’t be opened because there is no such
>   file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:/.file/id=6571367.12885025918 --
>   file:///Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.xxx.imageviewfix/Data/,
>   NSFilePath=/Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.xxx.imageviewfix/Data/file:/.file/id=6571367.12885025918,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c70d80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am late to this question but I found this works:

```
  NSArray<Class> *classes = @[[NSURL class]];
  NSDictionary *options = @{};
  NSArray<NSURL*> *files = [pboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];

  for (NSURL *url in files)
  {
     NSString *str = [url path];

     // TODO: do something with str.
  }
```

Unlike the other answer, dropping multiple files works with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Getting path of NSURL object gets the original filename. The only thing missing is the array of file paths which `NSFilenamesPboardType` used to give.

```
NSString *fileURL = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard] path];
```

Updated code:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
    NSDragOperation resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationNone;
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSPasteboardTypeFileURL]) {
        NSString *fileURL = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard] path];
        NSError *error;
        NSString *UTI = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] typeOfFile:fileURL error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[NSImage imageTypes] containsObject:UTI]) {
                resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationCopy;
            }
        }

    } else if ([[pboard types] containsObject:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF]) {
        resultingDragMask = NSDragOperationCopy;
    }

    if (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationCopy && resultingDragMask & NSDragOperationCopy) {
        return NSDragOperationCopy;
    }
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```